# spring data mongodb error on CurrentBSONType

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

i using spring data mongo 2.2.1

this is my workspace document in mongodb:

```
{
    "type" : "RDBMS",
    "databases" : [ 
        {
            "ip" : "10.100.0.190",
            "port" : "1521",
            "sid" : "bidb",
            "username" : "dev",
            "password" : "U2FsdGVkX18YslvyCFHRkINjM5cyQSBb20Y5ZKBPKmU=",
            "tableName" : "",
            "type" : "Oracle",
            "name" : "aml",
            "shape" : "database"
        }
    ],
    "creatorUsername" : "amir",
    "sharedUsers" : [ 
        "amir"
    ]
}
```

i need all workspaces that creator or shared users is me (amir). when i execute this query in mongo everything is ok

```
db.getCollection('workspace').find({$or:[{'creatorUsername':'amir'},{'sharedUsers':{$in:['amir']}}]},{'databases':1})
```

but when i use that in mongodb repository i get error:

```
    @Query(value = "$or:[{'creatorUsername':?0},{'sharedUsers':{$in:?0}}]", fields = "{'databases':1}")
    Set<Workspace.WorkspaceDataBaseProjection> findDataBasesByCreatorUsername(String username);
```

error message:

```
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:690)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:722)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:450)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.findDataBasesByCreatorUsername(Unknown Source)
    at ir.dotin.bi.apps.asha.workspace.WorkspaceService.loadDatabasesByUsername(WorkspaceService.java:129)
```

what is wrong?

UPDATE:

workspace.java

```
public class Workspace extends AuditDocument{

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private List<DataBaseShape> databases;
    private List<String> sharedUsers;

//getter and setter 

    public interface WorkspaceDataBaseProjection {
        List<DataBaseShape> getDatabases();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use array in the `$in` notation as in the `find` method : `{'sharedUsers':{$in: [?0]}}`, that is you are missing the square brackets I think.
Plus Query should start and end with curly brackets. Should be:
`{$or:[{'creatorUsername':?0},{'sharedUsers':{$in: [?0] }}]}`
In fact, you should copy paste the whole thing from your `find` method

Comment: Plus it would have been easier and arguably clearer, to use the query method keyword syntax, roughly  : `findByCreatorUsernameOrSharedUsersIn(String username, List<String> sharedUsers)` where second parameter is a singleton list same as first parameter

Comment: @OriDar thank you :)   Even though you found two problem in json, it still did not work. and throw `JSON reader was expecting a value but found '}'.` exception.  i use your second suggestion and use this `Set<Workspace.WorkspaceDataBaseProjection> findByCreatorUsernameOrSharedUsersIn(String username, List<String> usernames)`

Comment: It didn't work as `[?0]` should have been `[ :?0 ]`. Think it should be valid by then